# Executing error while executing sed command

Tags: linux, bash, sed, matching, text-parsing

Below given sed command is working fine on online BASH & KSH shell, but getting an error "Illegal operation --r" while trying to  run it on linux server.

I'm trying to make a regex to parse `MFBBMYKLAXXX` from first line.

```
echo "{1:F01MFBBMYKLAXXX2474811384}{2:O3001434181108BKKBTHBKBXXX12203020241811081534N}{3:{108:241C182AFFD4403C}}{4:
:15A:
:20:10168957
:22A:NEWT
:94A:BILA
:22C:BKKBBK8308MFBBKL
:82A:BKKBTHBK
:87A:MFBBMYKL
:15B:
:30T:20181108
:30V:20181109
:36:32,8308
:32B:THB2500000,
:53A:/610165
BKKBTHBK
:57A:BKKBTHBK
:33B:USD76148,01
:53A:CHASUS33
:57A:/04058664
BKTRUS33
:58A:MFBBMYKL
:15C:
:24D:ELEC/REUTERS D-3000
-}{5:{CHK:4117CD0206B7}}{S:{COP:S}}
" | sed -rn 's/.*\{1:F01([A-Z]{12}).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: Try changing `r` to `E`, `sed -En 's/.*\{1:F01([A-Z]{12}).*/\1/p'`

Comment: I'm still getting error:    sed: illegal option -- E
sed: illegal option -- E
-bash-4.1$

Comment: If you transcribed the error message correctly, the problem is that you have two dashes before `-r`. Linux *generally* supports `sed -r` but "Linux" is a very broad brush -- which distro and version, which `sed` version? (Try `uname -a`, `lsb_release -a`, `sed --version`)

Comment: Ultimately a defensive workaround would be to rephrase the regex as BRE: `sed -n 's/.*{1:F01\([A-Z]\{12\}\).*/\1/p'` or maybe even spell out ´[A-Z]` twelve times.

Comment: You just saved me.I'd be really thankful if you could explain me why you changed the \. Also the logic behind it as I am new to sed and regex? Why have you placed '\' before '(' and '{' not with every special character.And if there are characters like '+', '.' and ',' as shown in given examples as i'm getting sed: command garbled”    example 1):    sed -rn 's/.*\{2\:O([0-9]+)([A-Z]+).*/\1/p'  to parse BKKBTHBKBXXX  from {2:O3051540181108CIBBMYKLAXXX40470066801811081540N}

Comment: Also this example2)   sed -rn 's/.*1600([A-Z ]{17})([A-Z ]{17})([A-Z0-9]{5})([0-9,.]{12})([0-9]{8})([A-Z0-9]{16}).*/\6/p' <<< 'sed -sn 2p'  to parse  M999517511051514 from 1600MFBBMYKL         ALSRMYKL         IFT0000769771622820181105M999517511051514(in a single line)

Comment: Are you on Solaris?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes.  -bash-4.1$ uname -a
SunOS stqusmrxapp01 5.11 11.3 i86pc i386 i86pc

Comment: @tripleee Thanks
You just saved me.I'd be really thankful if you could explain me why you changed the \. Also the logic behind it as I am new to sed and regex? Why have you placed '\' before '(' and '{' not with every special character.And if there are characters like '+', '.' and ',' as shown in given examples as i'm getting sed: command garbled” example 1): sed -rn 's/.*\{2\:O([0-9]+)([A-Z]+).*/\1/p' to parse BKKBTHBKBXXX from {2:O3051540181108CIBBMYKLAXXX40470066801811081540N}

Comment: If you are on Solaris then by definition you are not on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `sed -r` (or in some dialects `sed -E`) is nonstandard and optional.

It selects a regex dialect called extended regular expressions, which allows you to express some things more succinctly.

POSIX basic regular expressions support pretty much the same facilities, but with an oddball syntax where you have to backslash some characters to obtain their special meaning (which in other words does exactly the opposite of what backslash escaping originally did).

So if you have an extended regular expression like `a+(b{2})c` then if your `sed` does not support either `-r` or `-E`, try `a\+\(b\{2\}\}c` without any special option, and hope that your `sed` is at least roughly on par with what POSIX specifies. (If you're serious about retrocomputing, this is unlikely, though.)

The original regular expression implementation by Ken Thompson only supported the regex metacharacters `[...]` and `.` and `*`, and for a long time, that's all `sed` supported, too.

Of course, you could always install a more modern `sed`. I know SunOS used to have some goodies in their `xpg4` directory but I have no idea if this was is the case in Solaris; if so, maybe you just need to add `/usr/xpg4/bin` to your `PATH`. (According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198905/when-to-use-xpg-version-of-a-command) it was true at one point in time at least.)

Comment: "Goodies" in this case is miseading; properly speaking, there was a way to make it suck slightly less.